# loading csv to C# System.ArgumentException

Tags: c#, csv, int32

I have the following code:

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"";", Path.GetDirectoryName(ofd.FileName)));
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM " + Path.GetFileName(ofd.FileName), connection);
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
Export_btn.Enabled = false;
Report_btn.Enabled = false;
Start_btn.Enabled = false;          
Start_btn.Text = "Loading CSV...";
adapter.Fill(dt);
```

And this csv:

[image]

But it return an import error showing that the epc column need int32 type. And the `expection = System.ArgumentException`
How can I fix it?

Comment: Take a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx `Path.GetFileName()`

Answer (score 0):

check datatable strcture `dt` . In `csv` file, `epc` column contain alphanumeric value so  in datatable `dt` , column `epc` should be `string` type.

Answer (score 0):

you need to give Schema.ini file to specify datatype of column in csv file More info can be found on MSDN 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353(v=vs.85).aspx

below is example of Schema.ini file.

```
[YourCSVFileName.csv]
ColNameHeader=True
Format=CSVDelimited
MaxScanRows=0
DateTimeFormat=dd-MMM-yyyy
Col1=A DateTime
Col2=B Text Width 100
Col3=C Text Width 100
Col4=D Long
Col5=E Double
```